# Django defering the foreign key look up

Tags: python, database, django, query-optimization

Working a django project and trying to speed up the calls.  I noticed that Django automatically does a second query to evaulate any foreign key relationships.  For instance if my models look like:

```
Model Person:
    name = model.CharField("blah")

Model Address:
    person = model.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Then I make:

```
p1 = Person("Bob")
address1 = Address(p1)
print (p1.id) #let it be 1 cause it is the first entry
```

then when I call:

```
address1.objects.filter(person_id = "1")
```

I get:

Query #1: SELECT `address`.`id`, `address.person_id` FROM `address`

Query #2: SELECT `person`.`id`, `person.name` FROM `person`

I want to get rid of the 2nd call, query #2.  I have tried using "defer" from django documentation, but that did not work (in fact it makes even more calls).  "values" is a possibility but in actual practice, there are many more fields I want to pull.  The only thing I want it to do is not evaluate the FOREIGN KEY.  I would be happy to get the person_id back, or not.  This drastically reduces the runtime especially when I do a command like: Address.objects.all(), because it Django evaluates every foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Having just seen your other question on the same issue, I'm going to guess that you have defined a `__unicode__` method that references the ForeignKey field. If you query for some objects in the shell and output them, the `__unicode__` method will be called, which requires a query to get the ForeignKey. The solution is to either rewrite that method so it doesn't need that reference, or - as I say in the other question - use `select_related()`.

Next time, please provide full code, including some that actually demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: I found that my __unicode__ did reference self.house.id.  That did seem to clear up the problem!  Thanks.  I can't upvote due to not enough reputation but people who can should upvote this!